# Why is this function space dense in this Bochner-type space? (Rogers and Renardy)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\phi(t) = \sum_{i=1}^N\beta_i(t)\phi_i(x)$, where $\phi_i$ is basis for space $V$, and $\beta_i \in C_c^\infty(0,T).$
Renardy and Rogers says that

> 1) Functions of the above form are dense in $H^1(0,T;V)$
>
> 2) Functions of the above form are dense in $C_c^\infty(0,T;V)$

Why is this true? How to prove it?

Edit:
They didn't define $H^1(0,T;V).$ I guess it consists of functions $u(t) \in V$ for each $t$ with $u(t) \in L^2(0,T)$ such that the derivative $u'(t) \in V$ for each $t$ with $u'(t) \in L^2(0,T)$ too.

$C_c^\infty(0,T;V)$ consists of functions $f(\cdot):[0,T] \to V$, so $f(t) \in V$ for each $t$. Furthermore $f$ is $C_c^\infty$ around $[0,T]$ wrt. $t$.

Comment: Define the spaces? I think the second one is probably in error ....

Comment: @RayYang see my edit.

Comment: What we need is a topology on $V$ to define the derivative, and also to define the notion of integral so as to make sense of a weak derivative for $V$-valued functions on $[0,T]$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo $V \subset H \subset V^*$ are Hilbert spaces (Hilbert triple) and all spaces separable.